# Displaying "laravel-love" likes count in blade file

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I am using the following to add a like/dislike system to my project: https://github.com/cybercog/laravel-love

I have the following models based on the installation guide:

User:

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements ReacterableContract
{
    use Reacterable;
...
```

Guide:

```
class Guide extends Model implements ReactableContract
{
    use Reactable;
...
```

In my blade file I have a `@foreach('$guides as $guide)` which displays a table of all guides. I am also trying to show the amount of likes for each guide using the following call `{{ $guide->likesCount }}` but nothing is printed on the page. Is my call perhaps wrong?

Comment: Use `->withCount('likes')` because it seems that you did not define any `likesCount` property in your model.

Comment: @rkg I tried that and got the following error `Call to undefined method App\Guide::likes()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this:

```
$guide->getReactionCounterOfType();
```

or

```
$guide->getReactionCounterOfType('Like');
```

Comment: Tried both and both gave `Call to undefined method App\Guide::getReactionCounterOfType() `

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try to user 
$guide->withCount('');
```

Comment: Tried that one but all I got was `Call to undefined method App\Guide::likes()`

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party, but you can try this

```
{{ $guide->viaLoveReactant()->getReactionCounterOfType('Like')->getCount() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel-Love v8.

Here's the solution to your question.

First, make sure that you have done the correct installation for both Models.
Your installation for both Models above is correct!

The complete guide is [here](https://laravel-love.readme.io/docs/installation-instructions).

Anyway, I assumed that you are getting it correctly and I will just put here how to show it in the blade.

In your Controller;

[Reactant Facade](https://laravel-love.readme.io/docs/reactant-facade)

[Reaction Counter](https://laravel-love.readme.io/docs/reaction-counter)

```
public function show($id)
{
        $guide = Guide::where('id', $id)
        ->findOrFail();

        $reactantFacade = $guide->viaLoveReactant(); //Get Reactant facade from Reactable model. 
        $reactionLikeCounter = $reactantFacade->getReactionCounterOfType('Likes'); // Determine if Guide reacted by User with the exact type of reaction (In your case it is 'Likes').
        $reactionCounter = $reactionLikeCounter->getCount(); //Reaction Counter - This will get the `count` from your `love_reactant_reaction_counters` table.  

        return view('layouts.guides.view')->with(compact('reactionCounter'));
}
```

In your Blade;

```
<span class="ms-1">{{ $reactionCounter }}</span>
```

If in case someone is looking for a simple Heart/Unheart through AJAX tutorial, I posted it on [Github Discussion](https://github.com/cybercog/laravel-love/discussions/74#discussioncomment-4663418)